# learning python and also trying to implement scrapy ..getting this error

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I am going through the scrapy tutorial http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html
and I followed it till I ran this command

```
scrapy crawl dmoz
```

And it gave me output with an error

```
2013-08-25 13:11:42-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.18.0 started (bot: tutorial)
2013-08-25 13:11:42-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2013-08-25 13:11:42-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial'}
2013-08-25 13:11:42-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
    execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 143, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 88, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 46, in run
    spider = self.crawler.spiders.create(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/command.py", line 34, in crawler
    self._crawler.configure()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 44, in configure
    self.engine = ExecutionEngine(self, self._spider_closed)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.downloader = Downloader(crawler)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/__init__.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.handlers = DownloadHandlers(crawler)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/__init__.py", line 18, in __init__
    cls = load_object(clspath)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 38, in load_object
    mod = __import__(module, {}, {}, [''])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/s3.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .http import HTTPDownloadHandler
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .http11 import HTTP11DownloadHandler as HTTPDownloadHandler
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 13, in <module>
    from scrapy.xlib.tx import Agent, ProxyAgent, ResponseDone, \
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/xlib/tx/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import client, endpoints
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/xlib/tx/client.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint, SSL4ClientEndpoint
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/xlib/tx/endpoints.py", line 222, in <module>
    interfaces.IProcessTransport, '_process')):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/zope/interface/declarations.py", line 495, in __call__
    raise TypeError("Can't use implementer with classes.  Use one of "
TypeError: Can't use implementer with classes.  Use one of the class-declaration functions instead.
```

I am not very familiar with python and I am not sure what is it complaining about

here is my domz_spider.py file

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)

And here is my items file

# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

from scrapy.item import Item, Field

    class DmozItem(Item):
        title = Field()
        link = Field()
        desc = Field()
```

and here is the directory structure

```
scrapy.cfg
tutorial/
tutorial/items.py
tutorial/pipelines.py
tutorial/settings.py
tutorial/spiders/
tutorial/spiders/domz_spider.py
```

here is the settings.py file

```
    BOT_NAME = 'tutorial'

    SPIDER_MODULES = ['tutorial.spiders']
    NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'tutorial.spiders'
```

Comment: Can you show us your settings.py?

Answer (score 32):

ok I found this somehow fixing the issue

sudo pip install --upgrade zope.interface

I am not sure what happened once issued this command but that solved my problem and now I see this

```
2013-08-25 13:30:05-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.18.0 started (bot: tutorial)
2013-08-25 13:30:05-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2013-08-25 13:30:05-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial'}
2013-08-25 13:30:05-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2013-08-25 13:30:05-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2013-08-25 13:30:05-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2013-08-25 13:30:05-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines:
2013-08-25 13:30:05-0700 [dmoz] INFO: Spider opened
2013-08-25 13:30:05-0700 [dmoz] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2013-08-25 13:30:05-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2013-08-25 13:30:05-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2013-08-25 13:30:06-0700 [dmoz] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/> (referer: None)
2013-08-25 13:30:06-0700 [dmoz] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/> (referer: None)
2013-08-25 13:30:06-0700 [dmoz] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2013-08-25 13:30:06-0700 [dmoz] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 530,
     'downloader/request_count': 2,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 14738,
     'downloader/response_count': 2,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 25, 20, 30, 6, 559375),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 10,
     'log_count/INFO': 4,
     'response_received_count': 2,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 25, 20, 30, 5, 664310)}
2013-08-25 13:30:06-0700 [dmoz] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Or sudo easy_install --upgrade zope.interface